# How to pass app version to front end with Spring and Angular?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, webpack, angular-cli

I need to be able to show in the front end the version number of the application that I get from pom.xml.

My solution at first was to have a api call to back end. But then I thought it would be better to set it during building.

My question is how can I set a global variable in angular that contains the version number from the pom.xml file using the new angular CLI build tools. I'm using Angular 8 if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that is currently possible in a straightforward way.

One approach that might work is to create a `version` property in your `environment.ts` file, with a constant, say `{VERSION}`. Then create a shell script that does the following:

1. Extract the version from the `pom.xml` file;
2. Replace `{VERSION}` in `environment.ts` with that version.

Then add your shell script to your build script before you build.

It's not ideal though. Ideally your front-end should be independent of the backend. By adding a back-end dependent script to your front-end build, you're adding an extra dependency between the two that may create issues down the line.

I wonder if your original idea (through the API) is not better. If you retrieve the version number through an API then you keep your front-end independent from your back-end. You could also add additional back-end information to the API call, such as date of build, current time at server etc.